# Google Cloud Functions: "Error: cannot communicate with function. Request rejected."

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I have one GCF `--runtime python37 --trigger-topic <pubsub_topic>` running for about one month, but just have three errors today.

`Error: cannot communicate with function. Request rejected.`

Since there are no **execution_id**s for such errors via Stackdriver Logs, it's hard to debug and trace.

BTW, there is no quota limit exceeding from `IAM & admin` - `Quotas`.

Comment: Could you share your requirements.txt? I would be looking for any libs with binary dependencies